# Why is my session variable not set here?

Tags: php, session

I am setting a session variable inside a function `studNameDetails1()`
while I am trying to retrieve it in a function `ViewMark()`. These are my two functions but there is no result:

```
function studNameDetails1()
{
     $_SESSION['ATTsub']=$sub_id = $ID[5];
}
function ViewMark()
{
      echo $_SESSION['ATTsub'];
}
```

When I echo the value in `viewMark()`, there is no value.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: That doesn’t matter; `$_SESSION` behaves like a normal variable during runtime.

Comment: Are the two functions being called as part of the same request?

Comment: @Prasoon saurav: session is started in my model page

Comment: @udaya If this is a MVC based application, I would think that a (front) controller should be the place to have session_start(), not in the model. Note, session_start() is used to both start and **resume** a session, say on another page. Take a look at the example in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to handle sessions.

```
    <?php // this starts the session 
session_start(); 

    // echo variable from the session, we set this on our other page 
echo "Our color value is ".$_SESSION['color'];  
echo "Our size value is ".$_SESSION['size'];  
echo "Our shape value is ".$_SESSION['shape']; ?>
```

All of the values are stored in the $_SESSION array, which we access here. Another way to show this is to simply run this code:

```
<?php session_start(); Print_r ($_SESSION); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `$ID` variable has not been declared inside the studNameDetails1 function, so when you try to access it, an undefined value. This will set the `$_SESSION['ATTsub']` and `$sub_id` variables to undefined, and so they will show as being empty when you try to print them.

If these variables have been declared outside the scope of the function, use the global keyword:

```
function studNameDetails1()
{
    global $sub_id, $ID;

    $_SESSION['ATTsub']=$sub_id = $ID[5];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: +1 For not assuming that there's more code in the function, as I did.